# Partial derivatives, directional derivatives and differentiability of a function

Tags: calculus

I'm studying the function $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}$ such that:

$$f(x,y) = \begin{cases}
                  y & \text{if } x=0
                  \\
                  x^2+x^2\sin(\frac{1}{x}) & \text{if } x\neq 0
                  \end{cases}$$

How to find the partial derivatives and directional derivatives at $(0,0)$? Do they exist?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hiperion, I made a few edits. (In particular, I removed the array enviroment, and used the "cases" command instead.) Hope it's ok.

Comment: Yes, it's ok. Thanks!

Comment: Since you accepted @Arturo's answer already, does this mean you know how to proceed with the directional derivative part?

Comment: I thought so, but I'm not so sure now

Comment: @Hiperion: What is the confusion?

Comment: @Arturo: Hi. I understand what you did. But what happens with the directional derivative in $(0,0)$? Thanks.

Comment: @Hiperion: *Which* directional derivative? (Oh, I didn't see that final part in the question).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You find partial derivatives the usual way: the parial derivative with respect to $y$ at $(0,0)$ is
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\Biggm|_{(x,y)=(0,0)} = \lim_{y\to 0}\frac{f(0,y) - f(0,0)}{y-0} = \lim_{y\to 0}\frac{y-0}{y-0} = 1.$$
While the partial derivative with respect to $x$ at $(0,0)$ is:
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\Biggm|_{(x,y)=(0,0)} = \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x,0)-f(0,0)}{x-0} = \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x^2+x^2\sin(1/x) - 0}{x-0} = \lim_{x\to 0}\left(x+x\sin\frac{1}{x}\right)=0.$$

**Added.** I had missed the "directional derivative" part.

The directional derivatives are similar: let $\mathbf{u}=(a,b)$ be a unit vector. Then by definition we have that
$$D_{\mathbf{u}}f(0,0) = \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(ha,hb) - f(0,0)}{h}.$$
If $a=0$, you are looking at the partial with respect to $y$, which we have already computed. If $a\neq 0$, then you get
$$D_{\mathbf{u}}f(0,0) = \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{1}{h}\left(h^2a^2 + h^2a^2\sin(1/h^2a^2)\right) = \lim_{h\to 0}\left(ha^2 + ha^2\sin(1/h^2a^2)\right)=0.$$